# Laravel Validation works but returns 200 instead of 422

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

I am building an SPA with Laravel 5.8 and vue; Laravel Passport for API authentication. All was well till last week when I noticed that I stopped getting 422 when validation fails. I started getting a 200 instead but validation fails and returns the usual "{"status":"failed","error":"The given data was invalid."}". That's all I get even when users sign up and validation fails at Laravel RegisterController. Before this, Laravel would return a 302 and identify the erroneous fields. Now all i get is a blank page with {"status":"failed","error":"The given data was invalid."}. Going into the API itself, it's same on form validation. 200 gets returned instead of 422 on failure. Therefore `<has-error :form="form" field="category"></has-error>` has stopped showing the errors across my app. It is so frustrating. I have checked my code a million and one times, everything looks perfect. And remember, this suddenly started a week back after over 4 months of correct operation.

Register Controller

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;


use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Notification;
use Auth;
use App\Mail\WelcomeMail;
use Mail;
use App\Notifications\newUser;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';


/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
         'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'mobile' => ['required', 'digits:11'],
         'state' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],

    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'surname' => $data['surname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
        'state' => $data['state'],
        'role' => $data['role'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'bonus' => 1000,
        'company' => $data['company']
    ]);

    $admin = User::where('role', 'admin')->get();

    Notification::send($admin, new newUser($user));

   Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($user));


      return $user;
}
```

}

Register.blade.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <link rel='manifest' href='/manifest.webmanifest'>

        <title>dafixas</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center signupTitle">
             <a href="/"><img src="img/Megalabourers_logo.jpg"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;dafixas</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

    </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card card-margin">


                <div class="card-body">
                     <p>You're Amazing! Let's Get to Know You.</p>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="firstname"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control @error('firstname') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname" value="{{ old('firstname') }}" required autocomplete="firstname" autofocus placeholder="First Name">

                                @error('firstname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>



                            <label for="surname"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="surname" type="text" class="form-control @error('surname') is-invalid @enderror" name="surname" value="{{ old('surname') }}" required autocomplete="surname" placeholder="Surname">

                                @error('surname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" placeholder="E-Mail">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="mobile"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input id="mobile" type="text" class="form-control @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="mobile" value="{{ old('mobile') }}" required autocomplete="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number">

                                @error('mobile')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                         <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="company"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input id="company" type="text" class="form-control @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="company" value="{{ old('company') }}" autocomplete="company" placeholder="Company Name">

                                @error('company')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>




                             <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="city"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                            <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state" class="form-control">
                        <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Please select Your State of Residence</option>
                        <option value="Abia">Abia</option>
                        <option value="Adamawa">Adamawa</option>
                        <option value="Akwa Ibom">Akwa Ibom</option>
                        <option value="Anambra">Anambra</option>
                        <option value="Bauchi">Bauchi</option>
                        <option value="Bayelsa">Bayelsa</option>
                        <option value="Benue">Benue</option>
                        <option value="Borno">Borno</option>
                        <option value="Cross Rive">Cross River</option>
                        <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
                        <option value="Ebonyi">Ebonyi</option>
                        <option value="Edo">Edo</option>
                        <option value="Ekiti">Ekiti</option>
                        <option value="Enugu">Enugu</option>
                        <option value="FCT">Federal Capital Territory</option>
                        <option value="Gombe">Gombe</option>
                        <option value="Imo">Imo</option>
                        <option value="Jigawa">Jigawa</option>
                        <option value="Kaduna">Kaduna</option>
                        <option value="Kano">Kano</option>
                        <option value="Katsina">Katsina</option>
                        <option value="Kebbi">Kebbi</option>
                        <option value="Kogi">Kogi</option>
                        <option value="Kwara">Kwara</option>
                        <option value="Lagos">Lagos</option>
                        <option value="Nasarawa">Nasarawa</option>
                        <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                        <option value="Ogun">Ogun</option>
                        <option value="Ondo">Ondo</option>
                        <option value="Osun">Osun</option>
                        <option value="Oyo">Oyo</option>
                        <option value="Plateau">Plateau</option>
                        <option value="Rivers">Rivers</option>
                        <option value="Sokoto">Sokoto</option>
                        <option value="Taraba">Taraba</option>
                        <option value="Yobe">Yobe</option>
                        <option value="Zamfara">Zamfara</option>
                    </select>
                             @error('state')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                          </div>
                      </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Create Password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="role" value="user">

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">
                                    Create My Account
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="loginnow">
                        Already Have an Account? Please  <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Log in</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="loginnow">
                        <span>By clicking on Create My Account, you agree to our <a href="/terms">terms & conditions</a> and <a href="/privacy">privacy policy</a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: show us some code. the minimal steps to reproduce this, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

So this worked for me:

```
if ($exception instanceof ValidationException && $request->expectsJson()) {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'The given data was invalid.', 'errors' => $exception->validator->getMessageBag()], 422);
}
```

in app\Exceptions\Handler.php, render function. But I can't still fathom what went wrong initially.